# Topology of $P(\omega)$ as $2^\omega$ (ultrafilters are open?)

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, filters

I'm looking for a sanity check more than anything else. We may identify $P(\omega)$ with $2^{\omega}$ in the obvious manner.

Let $U$ be a *principal* ultrafilter on $\omega$, so $U \subseteq 2^{\omega}$ (identifying $P(\omega)$ with $2^{\omega}$).

Is it true that $U$ is an open set with the cantor space topology on $2^{\omega}$? This is the topology generated by the basic open sets $N_s = \{ \alpha \in 2^{\omega} : s$ is an initial segment of $\alpha\}$ for every $s \in 2^{<\omega}$.

Since $U$ is principal, there is an $n \in \omega$ such that $U = \{A \subseteq \omega : n \in A \}$ so that for every string $\alpha \in 2^{\omega}$ with $\alpha(n) = 1$, $\alpha \in U$. But then there are $2^n$ many finite binary strings $s_i$ of length $n+1$ such that $s_i(n) = 1$, and then $U = \cup_{i \leq 2^n}N_{s_i}$ (if $\alpha \in N_{s_i}$ then it's initial segment is $s_i$ and thus $\alpha(n) = s_i(n) =1$, so $\alpha \in U$, and the other direction is similar.

So every principal ultrafilter is an open set in the cantor space? I'm pretty sure this is not true, but I also don't see the mistake either (I am quite sleep deprived right now) so I'm posting this here as a sanity check hoping that someone would correct me. Sorry if I'm missing something blaringly obvious.

Comment: "Principal ultrafilter" is a pretty fancy name to call $\{x:x(n)=1\}$. It's not only an open set, it's a clopen net. And a "principal filter", being an intersection of such sets, is a closed set.

Comment: In contrast nonprincipal ultrafilters are not even Borel

Answer (score 3):

It is true. That topology is just the product topology when $2$ is given the discrete topology. It has as subbase the sets

$$\left\{\alpha\in 2^\omega:\alpha(n)=0\right\}$$

and

$$\left\{\alpha\in 2^\omega:\alpha(n)=1\right\}$$

as $n$ ranges over $\omega$. Thus, the principal ultrafilter over $n$ is not just open: it’s a member of this subbase for the topology.